# WordPress keeps filtering by category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having an issue with the WP theme I'm developing. I have a `category.php` file that I use to list all posts based on their category. In this file, I have the following code:

```
$post_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'cat' => $cat_id
));
while($post_query->have_posts() ) { ...
```

This works just fine. But I also have a `blog.php` file in which I want to list all articles regardless of their category. I'm using this:

```
$post_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date'
));
while($post_query->have_posts() ) { ...
```

Now this doesn't work. I'm not getting any result, even when I don't use any argument in WP_Query. When I dump the `$post_query` variable, I'm able to see the MySQL query and it seems like WP is somehow filtering even in the second case. Here are the two queries:

First case:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC
```

Second case:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (6) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.ID DESC
```

I'm not sure why this part is used in the second case: `wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (6)`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved: I'm using a plugin to handle the multi-language aspect of the blog (Polylang), and it seems to create some custom taxonomies to list the articles that are in the current language only.

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_term_relationships` comes from Polylang plugin which is using `relationhsip` taxonomy.

As the plugin is hooked on some main query by altering it with a tax_query to show only current language contents.
Moreover, if you want to play with some custom tax_query, you would then need to not overwrite the Polylang's one, be careful.